# replacing files names with split output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to read filenames from a dir;
then within a for loop:
split names using a delimiter; store desired output in a new variable. Now I want to replace the original filenames in the directory with this new variable. So far I have gathered the following with the expected outputs shown:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test
write-output $files
```

Directory: C:\Test

```
1_N04532L_LEFT.JPG
2_N04532R_RIGHT.JPG
```

code continues

```
foreach ($file in $files)
{
   $nameArray = $file -split "_"
   $newName = $nameArray[1]
   write-output $newName
}

N04532L
N04532R
```

Any Ideas on how to accomplish this. I am not a programmer and there is lots of data on this, but it's not working for me.

Comment: You can rename files using [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.3). You already made the most difficult part, the rest is easy

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was using something like this the following within the for loop:  Rename-Item "$file" -NewName "$newName" but it's not working

Comment: So, did that not work? You shouldn't use quotes with your variables, just remove them. If there is an issue after then you need to explain it in your question instead of the comment section

Comment: What's not working? Did you get an error, or did it just not do anything? As mentioned above, you already are pretty much complete but, you can also just pipe to `Rename-Item` for a more concise solution.

Comment: Thank for the reply. As I have not used this before, I am trying to make sense of the Rename-Item cmdlet and how it works. I will post an update as I work it through...hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both commenters already explained, there is the [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) cmdlet for renaming files.
Since this cmdlet can take a scriptblock in its `NewName` parameter, you can use that to create a new filename.

```
# adding switch -File makes sure you do not also try to rename subfolders
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Test' -File  
foreach ($file in $files) { 
    $file | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1}' -f ($file.BaseName -split '_')[1], $file.Extension }
}
```

You can shorten this by piping the results from Get-ChildItem trhough one-by-one to the Rename-Item cmdlet.
Because we're piping the FileInfo objects here, we can make use of the [$_ automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#_)

```
# enclose the Get-ChildItem cmd in brackets so this will enumerate the files to completion
# before passing them on to te Rename-Item cmdlet.
# if you don't, files you already have renamed could be picked up and processed again..
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Test' -File) | 
Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -split '_')[1], $_.Extension }
```

Note: when renaming files, you can always run into naming collisions, upon which you will receive an exception

Comment: It Works! Thank you so much. This is so helpful! I was trying to use the Rename-Item cmdlet but it was hard to get my head around it as I don't use this on a regular basis. Many Thanks to you and the previous commentators for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @user1079898 You may want to mark this question 'done' do it is easier to find for others with a similar question.